# How to retrive the value of horseman.exists in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, promise

I just have a question regarding how to get the boolean value of horseman.exists to show up in the function horseFunction. When I print the value in horseFunction() it prints the promise object but in the main horseman chain, it prints the boolean fine.

Thanks!

```
var Horseman = require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-horseman");
var horseman = new Horseman();

function horseFunction(){
    console.log("inside horseFunction");
    var hasButton = horseman.exists("input[name='btnK']");
    console.log(hasButton) //prints the promise
    return hasButton;
}


horseman
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0")
    .open("https://www.google.com/")
    .waitForNextPage()
    .log("just opened google")
    .then( horseFunction )
    .log() //prints the result of horseman.exists("input[name='btnK']")
    .finally(function(){
        console.log("Finish!")
        horseman.close();
    });

//};
```

Comment: So you're saying `.exists()` sometimes returns a promise and sometimes a boolean? That's a horribly bad practise.

Comment: That's what I thought before but it turns out I was just doing two different things. See Roamer's answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two different things ...

```
// in horseFunction()
console.log(hasButton) // logs a promise
```

... and ...

```
// in the promise chain
.then(horseFunction).log() // logs the data that the promise delivers
```

So, it's clear that

- `hasButton` is a promise, not a boolean
- `.log()` is a *non-standard* "inspection" method offered by the object that `new Horseman()` returns. *You won't find `.log()` in general promise libs such as bluebird.js, when.js or in javascript's native promises.*

Try doing the same in `horseFunction()` as in the promise chain :

```
function horseFunction(){
    console.log("inside horseFunction");
    var hasButton = horseman.exists("input[name='btnK']");
    hasButton.log(); // <<<<<< should print a boolean
    return hasButton;
}
```

In all probability, `.log()` is transparent, so you might also try :

```
function horseFunction() {
    console.log("inside horseFunction");
    return horseman.exists("input[name='btnK']").log();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roamer, that makes a lot of sense now. I didn't know log() was a non-standard "inspection" method. I have another question though: when you say .log() is transparent, what do you mean by that?

I did return horseman.exists("input[name='btnK']").log(); and it did print the boolean

Comment: The sequence `var hasButton = horseman.exists(...); hasButton.log(); return hasButton;` ensures that the returned object is independent of whatever `.log()` returns. But if, as it seems, `hasButton.log()` returns `hasButton`, then the sequence `return horseman.exists(...).log();` will be equivalent. I chose to describe this characteristic of `.log()` as "transparent", thus avoidng technical term [monadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)), which is even less self-explanatory.

Comment: And when I say "non-standard", I mean from a general Promise perspective. Horseman's promises are highly "decorated" with all sorts of Horseman methods in addition to what you would normally expect of a Promise. `.log()` is one such method.

Comment: Thanks for all the clarificaiton Roamer, helped me understand everything a bit better. You the man ;)